# How to execute a function() created/printed real-time in a html pop-up using Javascript from the source page within the popup itself?

Tags: javascript, html, function, popup, call

I have a source HTML page from which I open a virtual (not bound to a file) pop-up by clicking a generic button and by which I push some Html and Javascript code in its `innerHTML`.

This is a short simplified extract of the Source Page in which I define the Html+Javascript content of the pop-up and open it:

```
<script language="javascript">
<!--
    function fxOpenWindow()
    {
        // Init objects
        var retVal = ''; // contains the Html+Javascript to push in the pop-up innerHTML
        var popup  = ''; // pop-up to open, not generated by loading a file but only by pushing the "retVal" code inside its innerHTML


        // constructing the HTML to push

        // defining a function() to show a simple alert : "1"
        retVal = retVal + '<script>';
        retVal = retVal + '  function fxMessage() { alert(1); }';
        retVal = retVal + '</script>';

        // defining the html object with which execute the above function
        retVal = retVal + '<button onClick="fxMessage();">CLICK ME</button><br>';


        // opening the virtual POPUP

        popup = window.open('','title');
        popup.document.body.innerHTML = retVal;
        popup.focus();
    }
-->
</script>

<button onClick="fxOpenWindow();">OPEN THE POP-UP WINDOW AND SHOW ITS CONTENT</button>
```

My problem is that I can't make the `fxMessage()` function work, it just doesn't do anything at all.

I have used the `eval()` method too, trying to make the string become live executable code:

```
// all these methods are a "NO-GO"
retVal = retVal + '<button onClick="fxMessage();">CLICK ME</button><br>';
retVal = retVal + '<button onClick="eval(fxMessage);">CLICK ME</button><br>';
retVal = retVal + '<button onClick="eval(fxMessage());">CLICK ME</button><br>';

// the "direct method" is the only one that works:
retVal = retVal + '<button onClick="alert(1);">CLICK ME</button><br>';
```

Since the real code is more complex, I have the need to use a function() for simplifying some recursively calls I have to write in order to dynamically build more html objects in the popup itself, so I DO really mind to write all the code inside the `onClick` event; another thing I'm not willing to do is to have the pop-up load a html file stored on the hard-disk in which I have wrote all the `retVal` as its html in order to be able to have the `fxMessage()` function working correctly: the pop-up must be just a virtual page resident only in memory the time is open.

My question is : is there a way to have the `fxMessage()` to be elevated a as function in the pop-up and make it work out its job?

Answer (score 1):

If you try to insert some `<script>` by `innerHTML` after the page load, it won't work (I've explained it yesterday [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58170209/8376184)).

So, move the `fxMessage`'s declaration to your script, like:

```html
<script>
fxOpenWindow(){
  //Code here
}
fxMessage(){
  //Code here
}
</script>
```

And call it simply `onclick="fxMessage()"`, no need for `eval` here.

Comment: So I have to have all the Javascript in the source-page and push out the results up to the pop-up; I'll read your explanation you linked me carefully.
Thank you FZs for your solution,

Comment: @F.Bas I'm glad that helped. Additional note to the linked answer: since that question was a bit different, the solution differs too; but the reason of the problem is the same.

Answer (score 0):

How cool is this ?

```
<script language="javascript">
<!--

    function fxOpenWindow(id) {
      var win = window.open('');
      var script = document.createElement('script');
      script.text = 'function fxMessage() { alert(1); }';
      win.document.head.appendChild(script);
      var retVal = '<button onClick="fxMessage();">CLICK ME</button><br>';
      win.document.body.innerHTML = retVal;
    }
-->
</script>

<button onclick="fxOpenWindow();">OPEN THE POP-UP WINDOW AND SHOW ITS CONTENT</button>
```

Basically, scripts added with .innerHTML aren't executed. For this you need to create a script node and append it to the child window's HEAD

Comment: I like the use you make of the [document] object, it comes in handy in a lot of ways;
your solution is working even in less fewer lines than mine too, and that is always a good thing. Thank you Bilal.

Comment: Happy to help ! you can close this issue now I guess :)

Answer (score 0):

My specific need is to have the pop-up to be able to create html objects inner-self using a function() (fxMessage() { ...create html objects... }); I have put at work all your answers in different scenarios; there are some differences between the two methods and both of them are working fine and smooth.